# Automatic Examples to be counted

Tags: books

how can we make the Examples to be counted automatically? I used \setcounter{setnumdepth}{2} in the preamble but it did'not worked

Answer (score 2):

Just make them a theorem-like structure, something like this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
```

defines an example environment, which has **Example** + **no** in upright boldface, the body of the example in normal upright font, numbered by section.

You can easily customise further the layout with the `thmtools` package.